# Storing a variable number of values per item

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to read and store in a  `defaultdict(list)` a csv file:

```
Pos   ID    Name
1   0001L01 50293
2   0002L01 128864
3   0003L01 172937
4   0004L01 12878
5   0005L01 demo
6   0004L01 12878
7   0004L01 12878
8   0005L01 demo
```

I would like the `ID` to be my keys and as values `Pos` and Name. However the number of `Pos` varies. For instance ID `0005L01` contains `Pos` 8 and 5 whereas `0001L01` contains `Pos` 1. Is there a way of doing that?
So far I got:

```
reader = csv.reader(open("sheet.csv", "rb"))
for row in reader:
       if any(row):
          dlist.append(row)

for k, g in groupby(zip(mylist, itertools.count()), key=lambda x: x[0][1]):
            map(lambda x: d[k].append((x[0][0], x[1], x[0][2])), g)
```

Comment: What is `mylist`? Does it include the `Pos` column? How is the result supposed to look? And are you aware that `groupby` will only group consecutive groups, i.e. you will get two groups for `0004L01`? Also, using a function with side effects in `map` is usually considered bad practice.

Comment: @tobias_k I will update my question with more info and code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method to create the expected dictionary:

```
import csv
d={}
with open('my_file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
     for row in spamreader:
     try :
         Pos,ID,Name=row
         d.setdefault(ID,[]).append([Pos,Name])
     except ValueError :
          continue
```

result:

```
{'0001L01': [['1', '50293']],
 '0003L01': [['3', '172937']], 
 '0002L01': [['2', '128864']], 
 '0005L01': [['5', 'demo'], ['8', 'demo']], 
 '0004L01': [['4', '12878'], ['6', '12878'], ['7', '12878']]}
```

As @tobias_k says, if you have not `pos` columns in your file you can use `enumerate` to create it manually :

```
import csv
d={}
with open('my_file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
     for Pos,row in enumerate(spamreader,1):
     try :
         ID,Name=row
         d.setdefault(ID,[]).append([Pos,Name])
     except ValueError :
          continue
```

Comment: @Manolete Maybe you have a row in your file that contains less than 3 column!

Comment: @Kasra As OP uses `zip(mylist, itertools.count())`, I suspect the `Pos` column is not actually included in the data.

Comment: @Manolete Any way i add a `try-except` to handle this problem!

Comment: @all I do have a `Pos` column. Thanks

Comment: The problem seems to be with using `' '` as delimiter while some columns are delimited with more than one space. Either just use `split` instead of csv-reader, or `Pos,ID,Name = filter(None, row)` to filter out empty columns.

Comment: @all  Is there any easy way of obtaining the position that an `ID` first appears in the csv file?